# How to display JSON Array in a html table using *NgFor?

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, angular7, ngfor

I try to display data of an array from external JSON file to a html table. I manage to read the data at console logs, but I can't display the data. I'm still new with Angular 7, so I might miss something important during coding and I have no idea about it.

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/https';
import { HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/https';
import { getRootView } from '@angular/core/src/render3/util';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor (private httpService: HttpClient) { }
  parameter: string;

  ngOnInit () {
    this.httpService.get('./assets/fyp2019-ff11e-export.json').subscribe(
      data => {
        this.parameter = data as string;   // FILL THE ARRAY WITH DATA.
        console.log(this.parameter);    
      },
      (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        console.log (err.message);
      }
    );
  }
```

Sample data from the json file:

```
{
  "GoogleSheet" : {
    "Data1" : {
      "LevelTankA" : 1.5,
      "LevelTankB" : 1,
      "MotorSpeed" : 15,
      "Time" : 1
    },
    "Data2" : {
      "LevelTankA" : 5,
      "LevelTankB" : 2.3,
      "MotorSpeed" : 15,
      "Time" : 2
    },
    "Data3" : {
      "LevelTankA" : 6,
      "LevelTankB" : 2.9,
      "MotorSpeed" : 20,
      "Time" : 3
    }
  }
}
```

a part of coding from component.html

```
  <table>
      <tr>
          <th>Tank A</th>
              <th>Tank B</th>
                  <th>Motor Speed</th>
                      <th>Time</th>        
      </tr>
      <!-- BIND ARRAY TO TABLE -->
      <tr *ngFor="let val of parameter; let i = index">   
    //prepare the key and grab the data key and values
    <td *ngFor="let obj of val">{{obj.LevelTankA | json}}</td>
    <td *ngFor="let obj of val">{{obj.LevelTankB | json}}</td>
    <td *ngFor="let obj of val">{{obj.MotorSpeed | json}}</td>
    <td *ngFor="let obj of val">{{obj.Time | json}}</td>           
      </tr>
  </table>
```

I have no idea why I can't bind the array to html table. I try various coding using *ngFor and *ngIf but still can't display the data.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the type of the parameter variable is string instead of array:

```
parameter: string ->  parameter: any[];
```

And also when getting the data from the service, the response should be handled as object.

```
this.httpService.get('./assets/fyp2019-ff11e-export.json').subscribe(
      data => {
        this.parameter = data;   // FILL THE ARRAY WITH DATA.
        console.log(this.parameter);    
      },
      (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        console.log (err.message);
      }
    );
```

Edit:
Also there is an issue with the json file, it should be like:

```
{
  "GoogleSheet" : [
    "Data1" : {
      "LevelTankA" : 1.5,
      "LevelTankB" : 1,
      "MotorSpeed" : 15,
      "Time" : 1
    },
    "Data2" : {
      "LevelTankA" : 5,
      "LevelTankB" : 2.3,
      "MotorSpeed" : 15,
      "Time" : 2
    },
    "Data3" : {
      "LevelTankA" : 6,
      "LevelTankB" : 2.9,
      "MotorSpeed" : 20,
      "Time" : 3
    }
  ]
}
```

And as there is a top level object, the ngfor has to be modified:

```
<tr *ngFor="let val of parameter.GoogleSheet; let i = index">
```

Comment: What is the type of the arriving data object?

Answer (score 0):

in my project using Json file data.

First create folder and create file parameter.json

I have modified your Json same like below

```
[
  {
    "LevelTankA": 1.5,
    "LevelTankB": 1,
    "MotorSpeed": 15,
    "Time": 1
  },
  {
    "LevelTankA": 5,
    "LevelTankB": 2.3,
    "MotorSpeed": 15,
    "Time": 2
  },
  {
    "LevelTankA": 6,
    "LevelTankB": 2.9,
    "MotorSpeed": 20,
    "Time": 3
  }
]
```

Path should be like

```
ProjectName\src\app\pages\module\_configuration\parameter.json
```

Import parameter.json in Component

```
import * as parameterData from './_configuration/parameter.json';
```

Declare Parameter as any like below

```
parameter: any;
```

initialize in ngOninit you will get data.

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.parameter= <any>parameterData.default;
  }
```

I have modified your HTML file.

```
 <table>
      <tr>
          <th>Tank A</th>
              <th>Tank B</th>
                  <th>Motor Speed</th>
                      <th>Time</th>        
      </tr>
      <!-- BIND ARRAY TO TABLE -->
      <tr *ngFor="let val of parameter; let i = index">   
    //prepare the key and grab the data key and values
            <td>{{ val.LevelTankA}}</td>
            <td>{{ val.LevelTankB}}</td>
            <td>{{ val.MotorSpeed}}</td>
            <td>{{ val.Time}}</td>
      </tr>
  </table>
```

As per my understanding i have given solution , i hope it will useful for you.

Comment: my imports seem to be undefined when I try to access a property like you did for parameter.json. I got error msg =>"ERROR in src/app/app.component.ts(5,32): error TS2732: Cannot find module './assets/fyp2019-ff11e-export.json'. Consider using '--resolveJsonModule' to import module with '.json' extension"

Comment: Hi that us very simple Goto src folder under Create file as "typings.d.ts", Paste this code declare var module: NodeModule;
interface NodeModule {
    id: string;
}
declare module "*.json" {
    const value: any;
    export default value;
}